# Jquery code not working in IE but working in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Does anyone see why this code wouldn't work in IE? Works in all other browsers.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#rss-east").rss("http://example.com/rss/waittime_east_rss.php",
  {
    ssl: true,
    entryTemplate:'{title}'
  }),
  $("#rss-west").rss("http://example.com/rss/waittime_west_rss.php",
  {
    ssl: true,
    entryTemplate:'{title}'
  })
})
```

Comment: Define "not working". Are there any console errors?

Comment: No related console errors.

Comment: Also this code utilizes a jquery utility called jquery-rss
https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss

Comment: If you are using ssl shouldn’t it be over https:// or just //..

Comment: You still have not told us what it's failing to do in IE (define "not working"). Also, are the two id's referenced div's or what in the html? Can you show the html and templates this code is for?

Comment: The code executes and uses an external library to pull data from an rss feed and put it into a div. The rss data shows in all browsers but IE. There is no log information. I might just be running into a limitation with the external library.

Comment: I am thinking it must have something to do with the execution order. But I am not sure.

Comment: Ok man. Last try by me, because repeating myself in text is really annoying. **Can you show the html and templates this code is for?** Make a working example so we can test it in IE.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up being a conflict with another jquery library. Thanks everyone for the help and suggestions.